# Simulate a game of Craps

Tags: code-golf, game, random

Craps is a fairly simple dice game often played in casinos. Even if you aren't a gambler (which I'm not), it's still a fairly interesting game. Here's the rules:

At the start of a game of Craps there's what is called the *come-out* round. The player rolls two d6s (six-sided die) and the two die rolls are added. If the result is 7 or 11, the person automatically wins (this is known as a *natural*). If the result is 2, 3 or 12 the person automatically loses (this is known as *crapping out*). Otherwise, the result is set as the *point* for the point round.

After this, the *point* round begins. During the point round, the player must continuously roll 2 d6s until the person rolls a 7 or his/her point from the previous round. If the person rolls a 7, they lose. If they roll their point, they win.

## Challenge

Implement a simple program that simulates a game of craps. If the person rolls a natural or a crap-out during the come-out round, the program should output "Natural: " or "Crapping out: " followed by the die-roll and then exit. Otherwise, it should output "Point: " followed by the point. Then, during the point round, it should output every die-roll until a 7 or the point is reached. If the person wins, it should output `"Pass"`; if they lose it should output `"Don't Pass"`.

## Reference Implementation

Groovy, 277 bytes

```
def a={return Math.random()*6+1};int b=a()+a();(b<4||b==12)?{println"Crapping out: "+b}():{(b==7||b==11)?{println"Natural: "+b}():{println"Point: "+b;for(;;){int x=a()+a();println x;(x==7)?{println"Don't Pass";System.exit(0)}():{if(x==b){println"Pass";System.exit(0)}}()}}()}()
```

[Try it online.](http://ideone.com/fork/gB0YGf)

## Sample outputs

`Natural: 7`

`Crapping out: 3`

```
Point: 9
4
8
11
9
Pass
```

and

```
Point: 5
3
7
Don't Pass
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins.

(DISCLAIMER: This challenge is not intended to promote gambling in any way. Remember, the house always wins.)

Comment: `You can't make your program shorter by picking a random number between 1 and 12 for the die roll; it must be two numbers picked between 1 and 6.` - What about picking a random value in [1, 12] from a distribution that is identical to adding two uniform random values in [1, 6]?

Comment: @Mego Whoa, old challenge. Yes that would be fine. I think that warning was mostly just to make sure people realized that a *uniform* distribution between [1, 12] isn't the same as a 2d6. I'll rewrite it a little bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Ruby 164

Pretty straightforward. Interesting features:

The crapping out cases are summarised as `r%12<4` and the remaining natural cases are summarised as `r%4==3`.

The initial string is stored in `c` and further rolls are taken only if this is later alphabetically than the single letter `?P` (which only occurs for `Point`.)

```
f=->{rand(6)+rand(6)+2}
s=0
r=f[]
print c=r%12<4?'Crapping out':r%4==3?'Natural':'Point',": #{r}
"
c>?P&&(until s==r||s==7
p s=f[]end
print s==7?"Don't ":"","Pass")
```

Comment: Love the way how you check for the remainder instead for 2,3,7,11 or 12 seperatly!

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3, 190 bytes

```python
from random import*
r=randrange
p=print
a=r(5)+r(5)+2
c=890145//3**a%3
p(['Point:','Crapping out:','Natural:'][c],a)
if c<1:
 while 7!=c!=a:c=r(5)+r(5)+2;p(c)
 p(['Pass',"Don't pass"][c==7])
```

This is based on [Celeo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/61504/39328); I replaced some lengthy conditionals with a magic number that encodes a LUT for each number, reused a variable, and did a few other miscellaneous golfs. Still room to golf; it's probably possible to get under 170.

I didn't try to use Python 2, so I don't know if it would be shorter.

Comment: Care to explain how you got that magic number and how it works?

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>226</s> 224 bytes

First pass and there's a lot of code there:

```python
from random import*
r=randrange
a=r(5)+r(5)+2
if a in[7,11]:print'Natural:',a
elif a in[2,3,12]:print'Crapping out:',a
else:
 print'Point:',a
 b=0
 while b not in[7,a]:b=r(5)+r(5)+2;print b
 print'Pass'if b-7else"Don't pass"
```

Thanks to [Mego](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/45941/mego) for 2 bytes!

Comment: Few issues with this. It doesn't print out "Point: " followed by the number if the roll wasn't a natural or a crap. Also, there should be a space between the : and the number.

Comment: Whoops! Fixed not printing 'Point: #'. In the output, there is a space.

Comment: Ah OK. I don't use Python very much anymore so I was uncertain about how the ,a works.

Comment: I golfed your code down to 198 in Python 3, which is 192 in Python 2. Do you want the suggestions, or should I post my own answer?

Comment: @ThomasKwa If you put a bunch of work into it, post as a separate answer so you can get some rep for it.

Comment: @Mego Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

### C99, <del>366</del> <del>312</del> <del>293</del> 277 bytes

This is my first post here, so I'm going to guess that this can be improved by a lot.

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define r rand()%6+1
#define p printf(
main(c,s){srand(time(0));s=r+r;int*a=s==7||s==11?"Natural:%d":2-s||3-s||12-s?0:"Crapping out:%d";if(a){p a,s);return 0;}p"Point:%d\n",c=s);do p"%d\n",s=r+r);while(7-s&&s-c);p(7-s)?"Pass":"Don't pass");}
```

#### Expanded Version

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#define r rand()%6+1
#define p printf(
main(c,s){
    srand(time(0));
    s=r+r;
    int*a=s==7||s==11?"Natural:%d":2-s||3-s||12-s?0:"Crapping out:%d";
    if(a) {p a,s);return 0;}
    p"Point:%d\n",c=s);
    do p"%d\n",s=r+r);
    while(7-s&&s-c);
    p(7-s)?"Pass":"Don't pass");
}
```

As you can see, there's a good amount of redundancy here that can most likely be done away with.

Credits to @Mego for helping to make this smaller.

Comment: As long as it compiles somewhere, you're good.

Comment: @Mego thanks for pointing that out, that managed to get rid of 19 bytes.

Comment: Got some more off getting rid of `a` and `b` and also using the subtraction method along with ternary operators.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP <del>230</del> <del>228</del> <del>218</del> <del>199</del> <del>192</del> 188 Bytes

186 bytes without the `<?`

```
<?$a=rand(1,6)+rand(1,6);$a%4==3?die("Natural: $a"):$a%12<4?die("Crapping out: $a"):print"Point: $a
";while(1){($b=rand(1,6)+rand(1,6))==7?die("Don't Pass"):$b==$a?die("Pass"):print"$b
";}
```

First attempt at code golf! Not sure if using `</br>` would be allowed though? As this would not work in a console (as a new line). Let me know if this is not allowed and will alter my code.

EDIT (16-8-16): After getting better at codegolf I noticed some possible improvements. This still works using the command line interface. Replaced `</br>` with an hard enter.

Comment: Natural is spelt "Natural" and not "Naturel".

Comment: Changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript 262

```
var r=(x=>Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1)),a=r()+r();if(a<4||a==12){alert("Crapping out: "+a)}else if(a==7||a==11){alert("Natural: "+a)}else{alert("Point: "+a);while(1){var b = r()+r();if(b==a){alert("pass");break}if(b==7){alert("dont't pass");break}alert(""+b)}}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>181</s> <s>183</s> <s>179</s> <s>178</s> <s>167</s> 165 bytes

<sup>-10 bytes thanks to mazzy</sup>
<sup>-2 bytes thanks to Xcali</sup>

```powershell
switch -r($z=&($x={(random 6)+(random 6)+2})){'7|11'{"Natural: $z"}'2|3'{"Crapping out: $z"}default{"Point: $z"
do{($m=&$x)}until($m-in7,$z)"Don't "*!($m-7)+'Pass'}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcndCoIwGMbxc6/ibbw51xdpkJB4VNBZdAcxUmswN5kTw7lrt6KTzp7/72l0X5r2WUo5YZW7qe2FvT9hbSIc8jDCV@4iw1Wha9iz5d9MPGOOpmMcU0cu3HaGywPgQDxNxt3HjoY3jVAP0J39HUVZ8U5aR65aqJ8FhXYR1nmIL@Y7ZYX81FqodIUDIyetqAWymH0xZUt65W1LvZ98EMSbTbwd546ceV0C3uBAMgixyoBSP70B)

Unrolled version:

```powershell
#Switch using regex on $z which is...
#&($x={...}) first assigns $x to a scriptblock then calls it, saving the return to $z
switch -r($z=&($x={(random 6)+(random 6)+2})){
    '7|11' {"Natural: $z"}
    '2|3' {"Crapping out: $z"}
    default{
        "Point: $z"

        #Call the diceroll scriptblock until you Pass,
        #while pushing each roll to output
        do{($m=&$x)}
        until($m-in7,$z)
        "Don't "*!($m-7)+'Pass'
    }
}
```

There's a few less sticking points now that the list-building logic has been rebuilt into a switch. I think it's still a pretty alright approach. +2 bytes fixing a bug.

Comment: awesome! shorten it up to [178 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYtBa8IwGEDv@RVZ@Or3xbayqihYctpgt@F9yAgsdYUmKWlk2qy/vXM77fZ4vNf7LxOGT9N1MzQqzXBViYJ2H97yncz/4XpihE9B933rztxfIhZE@KrjJegOCzz61kWUbwRREYxqAVeZbUtnNvIkf/VNwZhV6/JstvKUiwOHUbC2oRziEm4yNT5QTWD/ztL52Lp9AaNMYCewTDx7h5GL5cO9Kfcyx6MeBpzmibFqtaoev7MkXrQ1HN75QdR8AU3N8R78AA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: I think the condition `-notin (7,$z)` is not relevant tu the rule `During the point round, the player must continuously roll ... the previous round`. Now the loop finish when `$m` equals to `7` or the *first* round.

Comment: @mazzy That is a wording issue in the question. There's only two rounds. You set the Point only once in the `Come-out` round and that is your target number for the entire `Point` round. The `previous round` refers to the `Come-out` round

Comment: thanks. [168 bytes](https://tio.run/##TcnNisIwGIXhfa/iI3zTNP5hOmBBKbNQcCfegQSbjoE0KWmK0jTXXhU37s77nNbepetuUusJ6zJM3V356w2WLsOhTDN8lCFzwlS2gQ2bf808MhZoMXJOAzkJ3zuht4ADiZT/5ePvS/dOtK0y/2B7/7kqWYte@0DOVpmPJZUNGTZlig8We@OVftVSmWKBAyMHa6gHMnubkQWb07PoOhrjFJOEr1Z8Pf4EchSNBLzAluwgxXoHlMbpCQ "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy Dang, I always forget about regex switches. Good stuff

Comment: You should be able to take two more off by removing the `1?` from your craps regex.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 140 bytes

```perl
sub d{1+int rand 6}say$"=($p=&d+&d)%12<4?"Crapping out":$p%4-3?Point:Natural,": $p";if($"gt O){say$_=&d+&d until/7|$p/;say"Don't "x/7/,Pass}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JczRCoIwGEDhVxljmqI2LU3QxIu6rXyDWKxkINvPNqEwX71ldHvgfHDXQ@GcGW@IT1kkpEWaSY52s2EvgpuAQOPzyOehl232eYsPmgEI2SM1WlwR8PJk23ZqGaszs6NmQ4wrRADX4hEQ3Ft0Caefdf07aJRWDLR8E6D10vFRyZVF@ElLGnfMmNm5jwIrlDQuORXrNEu/)

Answer (score 0):

## R, 197 bytes

```
 r=sum(sample(6,2,T));if(r%%12<4)cat("Crap Out",r)else if(r%%4==3)cat("Natural",r)else{cat("Point",r);while(T){cat("",q<-sum(sample(6,2,T)));if(q==7){cat(" Don't");break};if(q>r)break};cat(" Pass")}
```

Ungolfed

```
r=sum(sample(6,2,T))
if (r%%12<4)  {
    cat("Crap Out",r) 
} else if (r%%4==3) {
    cat("Natural",r)
} else { 
    cat("Point",r)
    while (T) {
        q = sum(sample(6,2,T))
        cat("",q)
        if (q==7) {
            cat(" Don't")
            break
        }
        if (q>r) break
    }
    cat(" Pass")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 108 bytes

```
p|K?}J+OS6OS6,7 11"Natural"?}J[2 3 12)"Crapping out"k"Point"+": "JI!KW!}Z,7JIq7=Z
+OS6OS6=K"Don't "))+K"Pass
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/v6DG277WS9s/2AyIdMwVDA2V/BJLSosSc5SA4tFGCsYKhkaaSs5FiQUFmXnpCvmlJUrZSgH5mXklStpKVgpKXp6K3uGKtVE65l6ehea2UVxQs2y9lVzy89RLFJQ0NbW9lQISi4v//wcA)

First pass, can probably find a few savings.

Answer (score 0):

## [Runic Enchantments](https://github.com/Draco18s/RunicEnchantments/tree/Console), 151 bytes

```
R}}6'RA6'RA2++{{B͍
00B:7=S:b={+?\"Natural: "@>
pping out: "@\:2=}:3=}:c={{++?/"Cra
{:}≠   ?\ 6?;$$k\/ak$00B:$:7≠?\
"Don't "R"Pass"a/\$:$" :tnioP"\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwxCoMwFIDhPad4PAIOGRQLFl5J09rOReyaJXUoYomicQo5Qu/jIeyZUh2@4V/@cbZtE2MdQpHU110uhPfl78uyrKSjfNJLeqE0PoybR/MhwMuZDUNr39DPbk9NuQx02DTSeyFUirfRME9BrgsAKA2FOnHe6dR0fN/ybbwuSjO89zZxgDVWZprQpJoTRyBn275CHeMf)

After fixing a bug regarding random numbers (it was re-seeding every time `'RA` was called, and the seed was system time, resulting in massive runs of repeated values) this works correctly.

#### Explanation

Entry is on the second line, as the first line up until `B͍` is a function for rolling two dice and summing them.

Program flow, with some edge-wrapping and curled redirections unrolled for readability

```
   R}}6'RA6'RA2++{{B͍                      Roll 2, sum, return
   >00B:7=S:b={+?\                        Entry, make first roll, compare to 7 and 11.
                  "Natural: "@            If true, print "Natural: " and the value, else go down
                 \:2=}:3=}:c={{++?/       Compare to 2, 3, and 12.
"Crapping out: "@                         If true, print "Crapping out: " and the value, else go up
                     \$:$" :tnioP"\       Print "Point: " and value (IP is travelling RTL)
                     /ak$00B:$            Print newline, roll, print
:7≠?\                                     Compare to 7
    \"Don't "R"Pass"ak$$;                 If equal, print a newline and "Don't Pass"
     {:}≠   ?\                            Else compare to initial roll.
             R"Pass"ak$$;                 If equal, print a newline and "Pass"
              6?......ak$00B              Else return to roll loop by printing a newline
                                              and rolling again (. are skipped instructions)
```

There are only 4 NOP instructions (`{:}≠...?\.6?`) that would be very difficult to remove due to the space required on other lines (Namely the length of the `"Don't "` string).